# What is the T-SQL syntax to get the length of each column of a specific Table?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

My database is hosted on Microsoft SQL Server 2012 and I need to write a T-SQL query to pull the length of each column of a specific table.

Assuming my database is called `mydatabase` and the table is called `table1` with 3 columns (namely `col1`, `col2` and `col3`), how do I write my sql query to get that information?

Ideally, I want the output to be something like this:

```
ColumnName    Length
  col1          50
  col2          30
  col3          25
```

Additional info: I will need to run this query on several other tables where I don't know the number or names of the columns therein. So the query should output the names of the columns with their respective column length.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking for a Query that will return the Maximum permitted length of a column, Then you can View it from the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMN` view

```
SELECT
    ORDINAL_POSITION,
    COLLATION_NAME,
    CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
       WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'YourTableName'
```

Or if you are looking for the Maximum Lenght of the Data Stored is Each Column
Use MAX() and LEN() function

```
SELECT MAX(LEN(Col1)) FROM YourTable
```

Comment: Thanks. I have added some additional info to my question. Will the first query you mention perform the task mentioned in my ' Additional Info' ?

Comment: Yes, all you need is to specify the Table Name and it will return all the Column, there Data Types, Maximum Lenght, Ordinal Position, Default values and so much information that you may need

Comment: Please note that `CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH` is -1 for `varchar(max)`, `nvarchar(max)` and `varbinary(max)`. Furthermore, `CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH` is `NULL` for numerical types, datetime and other types that are not character or binary.

Comment: @JayasuryaSatheesh Thanks. I have another question if you don't mind. How do I modify the query to run on a Linked Server? It runs fine on the local server but I will need to compare the output with the same table located on Linked Server.

Comment: I'm not sure whether you will be able to perform the above Query using a Linked server, You may be able to execute the Select but it May not Return the rows due to security restriction I guess. Just give it a try

Answer (score 4):

I **assume** by length you mean, for example, that if it is a `varchar(50)` it has a length of 50. If it's a `decimal(18,2)` then you want to know Scale `18`, Precision `2`. This should help:

```
SELECT c.[name] AS ColumnName, st.[name] AS DataType,
       CASE WHEN st.[name] IN ('varchar','nvarchar') THEN c.max_length END AS Max_Length,
       CASE WHEN st.[name] NOT IN ('varchar','nvarchar') THEN c.scale END AS Scale,
       CASE WHEN st.[name] NOT IN ('varchar','nvarchar') THEN c.[precision] END AS [Precision]
FROM sys.tables t
     JOIN sys.columns c ON t.object_id = c.object_id
     JOIN sys.types st ON c.system_type_id = st.system_type_id
WHERE t.[name] = 'YourTableName';
```

Comment: Thanks. Looks like what I am after. I will give this a try and revert back.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `COL_LENGTH` to get this (more information can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/col-length-transact-sql))

You could write something like the following:

```
Select COL_LENGTH ( 'table1' , 'Col1' )
Select COL_LENGTH ( 'table1' , 'Col2' ) 
Select COL_LENGTH ( 'table1' , 'Col3' )
```

**EDIT:**

With the extra information provided I think the below is what you are looking for:

```
SELECT        
       t.name AS 'Table_Name'
      ,c.name  AS 'Column_Name'
      ,I.CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH 
      ,I.DATA_TYPE
FROM  sys.columns c
JOIN  sys.tables  t   ON c.object_id = t.object_id
JOIN  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS I on I.COLUMN_NAME = c.name
```

You will probably have to add a where clause in as this is currently looking for everything on a database.

By joining the `sys.columns` and `sys.tables` with `information_schema.columns`
You can find the length of columns/tables with out needing to know the name.

Comment: Please note that this is the length in _bytes_, not characters. For nchar and nvarchar, that makes a difference. Also note that `varchar(max)` yields -1.